# Horizontal scroll on mousewheel on list : reverse direction

Tags: jquery, css, html, mousewheel

I implement this code which working fine when i use mousewheel to scroll on my horizontal list :

```
$('#wall_list_ul').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 70);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Problem is that when i use :

- mousewheel to go UP, my list scroll from the left to the right. And
- mousewheel to go DOWN, my list scroll from the right to the left.

I would like to reverse this behaviour : when i use :

- mousewheel to go UP, my list scroll from the right to the left.
- mousewheel to go DOWN, my list scroll from the left to the right .

How can i adapt my code to do that ?

Comment: Have you tried `this.scrollLeft += (delta * 70);` (so INcrease the scrollLeft value)?

Comment: I was the trick ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my simple comment already was the answer to the question, I'll just post it here as well.

To change the direction, you just need to inverse the action on using the mousewheel. So, instead of DEcreasing the scrollLeft value

```
this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 70);
```

INcrease it by using

```
this.scrollLeft += (delta * 70);
```